# Can I stop XCode from breaking on a fatalError/preconditionFailure?

Tags: swift, xcode

I've got some conditions where I need my frameworks to report a `fatalError` or a `preconditionFailure` and crash. I have set up some unit tests around these conditions to make sure they hit correctly.

It works really well if the unit tests are run without a Test Host application, but the moment a Test Host application is involved, any `fatalError` or `preconditionFailure` hits an automatic XCode break with the message `Thread 1: Fatal error: <CUSTOM ERROR HERE>`. and stops the execution of the rest of the tests until I press the Continue program execution button manually.

This is obviously an issue because I can't just let my tests run in the background and I need to be actively hitting the `Continue` button every time one of these tests hits which is quite annoying.

Is there any way to disable this XCode break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is fixed in Nimble 7.1.3, a library which I use to test these particular cases. I also found this specific issue in the Nimble library [issue 478](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble/issues/478) which has a comment on a workaround you can use to disable the debug executable when running you tests. Hopefully this helps anyone else stuck with the same problem I had.

Comment: Don't you think your question/answer would be more useful if the question had _mentioned_ Nimble?

Comment: Fair point matt, but the question is not limited to Nimble. I only use this library to do the asserts, it would happen even if I didn't use the library and I had other ways of asserting that didn't include the workaround spoken about in the issue above, and/or the fix from this link https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlPreconditionTesting/commit/ce96cb1d81644b92c66fd2b622260905526a7c5f